# Excel 2013: “The picture is too large and will be truncated.”

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, cut-and-paste

This error message started popping up in Excel as soon as I hit cut or copy.  I don't know when it started or why and it happens every time.  Running Windows 7, with Office 2013 Pro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When researching this issue, I found a bunch of solutions which I may update here later.

***None however***, worked for me, personally.

In the end, the culprit was **Actual Windows Manager** / **Actual Multiple Monitors** which has an option for *"enabling a [system-wide] clipboard history"* which you can set as deep at 25 entries.

---

Upon more research, I've come to the conclusion that **other/any 3rd party program that hooks into the windows clipboard** could cause the same issue.  So, I suggest you look at this option before any others, as it's a quick test/fix:

- I disabled the clipboard history option in Actual Windows Manager
- then tried the cut or copy in Excel again, the error was gone
- In my case, I did not need to restart either Excel or AWM, but I would suggest trying both if this solution doesn't work for you right off the bat
- If there's no simple option for disabling, try closing or killing (in task manager) any process related to the suspected 3rd party program
- Obviously, you can re-enable the 3rd party program/option again when you're not using excel, or just live with the error.

***Further info:*** I've also read about this occurring with **TeamViewer**, when enabling the "syncing clipboard between the local host and the remote session" option

Comment: Actual Windows Manager / Actual Multiple Monitors was the culprit for me.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. This occurred while I was connected to another machine via RDP. Disabling the clipboard sharing for the RDP session (under local resources) resolved.